# Is there an elegant way to use a class's private variable's method in kotlin?

Tags: android, class, kotlin, methods, structure

I'm building a class structure like the following:

```
class A {
    fun methodA() {}
}

class B(private val a: A) {
    fun methodB() {}
    //fun methodA() { a.methodA() }
}

class C(private val b: B) {
    fun methodC() {}
    //fun methodB() { b.methodB() }
    //fun methodA() { b.methodA() }
}

fun main() {
    val c = C(B(A()))
    
    c.methodC()
    c.methodA()
    c.methodB()
}
```

Class A is part of class B, and class B is part of class C.

I've commented out the way i'm using the methods. I want to use the methods of class A and B from class C, but every time i add a new method to class A or B, i have to write a function in all the other classes up in the structure, because in the end only class C will be used.

Comment: Extract methods you want to expose in each class to an interface, make said class implement it and use [delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html) feature

Comment: make class B and class C  inner class

Comment: Too many classes to make them inner, it'd make the code a mess, but yes, it'd work too. The delegation seems to be the solution in this case.

Comment: This comment doesn't help the problem, but i'm writing a chart in android, where a chart has a chartarea (besides the title and legend). The chartarea can be plot too, and the plot contains axes. To set the axes color you should call chart.chartArea.axes.color =... instead of chart.axisColor = Color.RED, also you'd need to keep those elements public, which i don't intend to.